# three li with equal width

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I would like to have three `li` elements with equal width. I used `calc`, however the code does not work.

```
width:calc(100%/3);
display:inline-block;
```

**Snippet:**

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
}

ul li {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Phone</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Imprint</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:flex` in `ul` and `flex: 1` in `li`

```css
body {
  background: lightblue
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Phone</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Imprint</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
</ul>
```